# Java Plotting Graphs

Tags: java

I recently asked about how to plot graphs in Java and I was recommended JFreeChart. After researching it I couldn't find a way to do what I want to (simply plot some Point objects that are listed in an ArrayList and then draw a line through them as they are listed in the list). I would appreciate it if someone could help me get started with some code and if you could explain it to show me how to do this as I have looked around and can't find what I am looking for. I don't necessarily need JFreeChart code just preferably Swing/ JPanel. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried?. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions and try to improve your question.

Comment: I haven't tried any code specifically, I have just researched the topic and I am no wiser as to what I need to do to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFreeChart's xy plot will do exactly what you want.
http://www.javaresources.biz/jfreechart_tutorial.jsp

Comment: Thanks, do you know what that ChartFactory bit is because that's coming up as an error? Edit: Fixed that now. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to actually get it to show the panel for this graph?

Comment: I think you can create a ChartPanel (http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#ChartPanel(org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart) and add it to your frame or JPanel.

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks. The problem I've got now is that the line is drawn in the wrong order, is there a way to specify order for the line?

Comment: I think you can sort your dataset itself in correct order. I don't think it will be straight forward to override the defaulting ordering.

Comment: My dataset is in the correct order. If it's ordered like (1,3),(1,5),(2,1) it draws the line like (1,5),(1,3),(2,1). Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can try to put 1,5 as 1.1,5 so that x coordinate is a bit different. I don't know how Jfree chart sorts internally if two values are having same x corrdinates.

Comment: I can't do that because of what I'm doing before hand with the points. Is there another graph type like scatter that allows me just to draw lines?

Answer (score 2):

The [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/) package offers an nice plotter (JXGraph). The [Demo](http://swinglabs-demos.java.net/demos/swingxset6/swingxset.jnlp) shows how to use it -You can find the JXGraph on the left side at the buttom.